# Cron service running but not visible by "top"

Tags: cron, freebsd

I'm on my freeBSD server. 
Cronjob suddenly stop working. 
When I run "top" the service is not listed. 
But when i check "service cron status" , it is running with given PID. 
I restarted the service and even server but the problem still persist. 
How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this,
`ps -ef | grep cron`

Answer (score 1):

`top` doesn't show all processes (at least not the version I use). Normally it just shows the most active processes - as many as will fit in the window.

I'm not familiar with FreeBSD - is the `cron` daemon not named `crond`?

Troubleshooting daemons usually means

1) Check syslog - also check syslog configuration.
2) Read the man page for the daemon and restart it with debugging enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Normally we would use `ps` or `psgrep` for this, because `top` only shows the top screenful.  (On the Linux `top` command I see you could contrive to filter by typing oCOMMAND=cron).  I expect your cron is running.  Maybe you have another problem with it though?